# Detect mouse click with java while in a game

Tags: java, c++, mouse

I am thinking to make a simple robot app which would record all movements and clicks done by the use and then repeat them.

I can do that with a glasspane but my question is, would a GlassPane work if I tried to use the program while in a game? For example, world of warcraft since bots are popular in MMO's, what else could I use?

I know of mouse hooks, which based on c++ I think, but I do not know how to use them in java.
If that is the only way, can someone give me direction to an understandable document regarding using mouse hooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and I know a lot of people have looked for this, that is why I am posting so they can also see, I found a perfect library for this, you can find it at :

https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) for an easy way to listen for all events in your application.

Comment: would this work if the click was not made on any component of my application, but an entirely different one all together? Again, example wow? I apologize if I seem like I don't trust your answer, but everyone told me it's impossible so I'm amazed this would actually work

Comment: As I stated in my answer, it will only listen for events in your application.

Comment: yes I saw, but I thought you would answer regarding my issue, however, thank you for the tip